# Group data rows by near time

Tags: sql-server, datetime, group-by

Here is the problem I am facing:
I got a large table containing rows, I want to group them by near time, more specifically the time difference less than 2 minutes, example as following
With following input data:

- A 16:01:01
- B 16:01:20
- C 16:14:02
- D 16:15:01
- E 16:20:02

the expected result is

```
16:01:01 2
16:14:02 2
16:20:02 1
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: if you have rows with time 16:02:15, 16:03:13, will they fall into first group or not?

Comment: Roman, Yeah, it should fall into same group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),
               DATEADD(minute, (DATEDIFF(n, 0, time) / 2) * 2, 0),
               108),
       COUNT(*)
FROM times
GROUP BY DATEDIFF(n, 0, time) / 2
```

**Explanation:**
`CONVERT` displays a `DateTime` in `hh:mm:ss` format (= 108).
`DATEDIFF` converts to minutes and then divides by two, rounding to an integer so each `GROUP` of 2 minutes resolves to the same integer.
`DATEADD` is used to convert this number of minutes back to a `DateTime`, having multiplied by 2 to get back to the correct (rounded) time.

See [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/85014/22)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SQL server 2012, you'r in luck and you can use `lag` function and rolling total `sum`:

```
with cte as (
    select
        case
            when datediff(mi, lag(data) over (order by data), data) <= 1 then 0
            else 1
        end as ch,
        data
    from test
), cte2 as (
    select
        data, sum(ch) over (order by data) as grp
    from cte
)
select
    min(data) as data, count(*) as cn
from cte2
group by grp
```

[**sql fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/eb9b6/6)

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @m_TestTable table
(
DateRecorded datetime

)

Insert into @m_TestTable Values ('16:01:01' )
Insert into @m_TestTable Values ('16:01:20' )
Insert into @m_TestTable Values ('16:14:02' )
Insert into @m_TestTable Values ('16:15:01' )
Insert into @m_TestTable Values ('16:20:01' );

With tblDifference as
(
Select Row_Number() OVER (Order by DateRecorded) as RowNumber,DateRecorded from @m_TestTable
)

select cur.DateRecorded as prvD, prv.DateRecorded as prvC, dateDiff(n, cur.DateRecorded,prv.DateRecorded)  from tblDifference cur LEFT OUTER JOIN tblDifference prv 
ON cur.RowNumber = prv.RowNumber + 1
```

this will give you the time difference in minutes between 2 rows. You can select any row that has a time difference less then 2 mins. It will also give you the upper and lower value.

It should be usefull to find any values closer then 2 minutes apart.

```
prvD                    prvC                    Diff
1900-01-01 16:01:01.000 NULL                    NULL
1900-01-01 16:01:20.000 1900-01-01 16:01:01.000 0
1900-01-01 16:14:02.000 1900-01-01 16:01:20.000 -13
1900-01-01 16:15:01.000 1900-01-01 16:14:02.000 -1
1900-01-01 16:20:01.000 1900-01-01 16:15:01.000 -5
```