# Need to group by date +/- 1 second

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have tried search for an answer to this, but could not find an answer. sorry if my search keywords weren't correct.
Hopefully this makes sense.
Say I have a table A that contains data like, which is data stored by 2 independent machines (systemID A and B), collecting error code from the same system.

```
StartDateTime           systemID    HostID   Error
01/01/17 13:49:11           A        1         6
01/01/17 13:49:11           B        1         6
01/01/17 13:53:11           A        2         5
01/01/17 13:53:12           B        2         5
01/01/17 13:53:13           A        1         6
01/01/17 13:53:13           B        1         6
```

I want to GROUP BY StartDateTime, so have a query

```
SELECT [StartDateTime], [HostID],MAX([Error])
FROM A
GROUP BY [StartDateTime],[HostID]
```

Which works except rows 3 and 4 should be combined, but due to rounding of the date appear as separate entries 1 second different.

I can't query by systemID only, as it maybe only 1 machine obtains the error.

Is there a way I can group by StartDateTime field +/- 1 second in sql?

Comment: is the grouping always means to be 1-2, 3-4, 5-6, 7-8, 9-0? why wouldn't (for example) rows 4, 5, and 6 be grouped?

Comment: What does mean `LAST` ??

Comment: Immediately I see a big question here.  Suppose there are a series of records, each of which are within 5 seconds of each other.  How do you define a group/island in this case?

Comment: Show us how you form groups from the above 6 records.  How many groups are there?

Comment: Are you sure this is SQL Server as it doesn't have a `LAST` function?

Comment: Apologies, I tried to simplify the question and the example data used.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18299263/group-data-rows-by-near-time

Comment: Group would not always be 1-2,3-4 but can be 2-3,4-5.
The output I am after is 
`code`
    StartDateTime           HostID   Error
    01/01/17 13:49:11        1         6
    01/01/17 13:53:11        2         5
    01/01/17 13:53:13        1         6

But what I get is
`code`
    StartDateTime           HostID   Error
    01/01/17 13:49:11        1         6
    01/01/17 13:53:11        2         5
    01/01/17 13:53:12        2         5
    01/01/17 13:53:13        1         6

Comment: So how do you know the above isn't grouped into `123, 45` or `1234, 56`?

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: Piggy backing on @TimBiegeleisen there is a major issue with how you are looking to solve this problem. You could potentially end up with far more records in your grouping then you assume if multiple separate records round incorrectly in rapid succession. I would assume that you would want to alter the source of this data if you have the ability and change your rounding function to utilize either floor or ceiling to properly handle the milliseconds of the records. If you have no control over this data then you wont be able to definitively group records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there is a more simple solution and this will require SQL Server 2012+ but this should do the trick.

```
-- Sample data
DECLARE @A table (StartDateTime datetime, systemID char(1), HostID tinyint, Error tinyint)
INSERT @A  VALUES
('01/01/17 13:49:11','A',1,6),
('01/01/17 13:49:11','B',1,6),
('01/01/17 13:53:11','A',2,5),
('01/01/17 13:53:12','B',2,5),
('01/01/17 13:53:13','A',1,6),
('01/01/17 13:53:13','B',1,6);


-- solution    
SELECT
  HostID,
  startDateTime = 
  CASE 
    WHEN ABS(DATEDIFF(SECOND,startDateTime,Prev)) IN (0,1)
    THEN Prev ELSE StartDateTime
  END,
  Error = MAX(Error)
FROM
(
  SELECT *, 
    Prev = LAG(startDateTime,1,startDateTime) OVER (PARTITION BY HostID ORDER BY RN)
  FROM
  (
    SELECT
      [HostID],
      RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY HostID ORDER BY [StartDateTime]),
      [StartDateTime],
      [Error]
    FROM @A
  ) prep
) prep
GROUP BY 
  HostID,
  CASE 
    WHEN ABS(DATEDIFF(SECOND,startDateTime,Prev)) IN (0,1) 
    THEN Prev ELSE StartDateTime
  END;
```

**Returns**

```
HostID startDateTime           Error
------ ----------------------- -----
1      2017-01-01 13:49:11.000 6
1      2017-01-01 13:53:13.000 6
2      2017-01-01 13:53:11.000 5
```

Comment: Thanks Alan, using LAG was the trick that solved the problem. I did it slightly differently, but you pointed me down the right path